# Crontab is scheduling jobs but not executing

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, cron

I'm currently making a GUI application that at one point asks the user to input their email and a future date. I am then setting a cronjob that emails the user a reminder on that future date. The directories and files of the project look something like this.

```
|--GUI_application
    |--email_sender
    |   |--__init__.py
    |   |--email.env
    |   |--send_email.py
    |--venv
        |--interface.py
```

The send_email.py file contains a function called send_email, which I've imported into the interface.py file. I have bound the send_email function to a Tkinter widget in the interface.py file. I'll include the send_email.py file (without imports) below.

```
def send_email(recipient, subject, body):

  path = "/path/to/GUI_application/email_sender/email.env"
  
  load_dotenv(path)

  SENDER = os.environ.get("GMAIL_USER")
  PASSWORD = os.environ.get("GMAIL_PASSWORD")

  message = EmailMessage()
  message.set_content(body)
  message["Subject"] = subject
  message["From"] = SENDER
  message["To"] = recipient
  server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
  server.login(SENDER, PASSWORD)
  server.send_message(message)
  server.quit()


 if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not len(sys.argv) == 4:
      raise Exception('Invalid number of arguments')
    sys.exit(send_email(*sys.argv[1:]))
```

In the interface.py file, I've included the send_email function inside a function called set_reminder which is bound to the Tkinter widget (the 'set reminder' button). Again, I'll include what this looks like below.

```
    def set_reminder(self, year, month, day, email):

      year = int(year.get())
      month = int(month.get())
      day = int(day.get())
      email = email.get()

      cron = CronTab(user='username')
      email_subject = self.construct_email_subject()
      email_body = self.construct_email_body()
      cron_comment = self.names_of_projects[self.index_of_finished_project] + '_reminder'

      job = cron.new(comment=cron_comment, command=f"python3 /path/to/GUI_application/"
                                                   f"email_sender/emailbot.py '{email}' "
                                                   f"'{email_subject}' '{email_body}'")


      job.setall(datetime(year, month, day, 09, 00, 00, 000000))


      cron.write()
```

When I load the application and click the 'set reminder' button -- thereby executing the set_reminder function -- I notice that the job is scheduled (I can view it in the macOS terminal if I type 'crontab -l'). Despite that, however, the email is not sent.

I have noticed that, in loading the macOS terminal, I'm told 'you have mail'. When I load the mail I see the email constructed by the send_email function. I just wondered if anyone might be able to explain why the email is not sent to the right email address?

After googling, it looks like the most common problem people have is that cron cannot find their environment variables, though I'm not sure this is the case here as when I view job scheduled in the macOS terminal I can see the environment variables.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apple [deprecated the use of cron](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-CH1-SW8) in favour of Launch Agents, controlled by the launchd process.

> Note: Although it is still supported, cron is not a recommended solution. It has been deprecated in favor of launchd.

You can create a timed job using launchd, as [documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-CH1-SW1)

It's also worth noting that the documentation states

> Because installing cron jobs requires modifying a shared resource (the crontab file), you should not programmatically add a cron job.